# Как можно привязать scrollbar к label в tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Как можно привязать scrollbar к label в tkinter.

```
from tkinter import *
def show_list():
    global anime_list
    scroll = Scrollbar(window)
    scroll.pack(side="right", fill="y")
    anime_list = Label(text=Anibot_lists.list, font=("Times Roman", 12), justify=LEFT, borderwidth = 5,
         relief="sunken")
    anime_list.place(relx=.3, rely=place_list)
```

Я не стал выкладывать весь код, но вся проблема тут именно в

```
scroll = Scrollbar(window)
scroll.pack(side="right", fill="y")
```

Как привязать скроллбар к моему `anime_list`

Comment: Никак. У Label нет методов взаимодействия со Scrollbar'ом.

Comment: С Label просто не получится, можно использовать Entry без рамки, например